# RTX 3070 невероятно плохо работает с PyTorch

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, cuda, nvidia, pytorch

Есть проблемма, RTX 3070 8 GB, очень плохо работает с PyTorch (CUDA). Тоесть, в теории она работет, но операции которые обычно занимают 1-2 секунды, она исполняет 10-15 минут. В это время температура ядра видеокарты прилично возростает. Устанавливал официальные драйвера - не помогло. Пробовал cudatookit 9 и 10 версий - тоже не помогло. На ПК установлен Windows 10, I7-9700F, 32 GB ОЗУ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена - установил последнюю версию ночной сборки PyTorch

Comment: укажите номер версии в ответе пожалуйста